# Frameworks for hacklang?

Tags: frameworks, hacklang

Hacklang may still be relatively new but are there any frameworks (MVC for instance) that are well-documented for it ? I've stumbled accross [Fastuc](https://github.com/fastuc/framework) or [Hack-mvc](https://esokullu.github.io/hack-mvc/) but they don't seem ready yet and the documentation is quite scarce;

Any thoughts ?
Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 10):

First, remember that, since Hack is backwards-compatible with PHP, any PHP framework can be used in Hack. You won't get the benefits of typing code interacting with that framework of course, but the type system was carefully designed to deal with missing type information ("gradual typing"). So if you want to use Laravel, Symfony, etc, you can do so perfectly fine while still writing the code using them in Hack.

As for pure Hack frameworks, you can look at the [Hack language section of the HHVM blog](http://hhvm.com/blog/category/hack) which contains a few "community roundups". One of the most active today is probably [Titon](https://github.com/titon/framework), though I've not used it myself and so can't say how complete or ready to use it is.

Comment: Yes, I know I could use PHP frameworks but my aim is to really take advantage of all the new and improved features of hack, such as Async, etc.. I'll have a look at Titon, thanks !

Comment: First link is broken

Answer (score 9):

At this point in time [PHP frameworks seem to be dropping Hack support](https://github.com/cakephp/phinx/issues/1101) and [Hack seems to be going down the path of truly diverging from PHP](https://hhvm.com/blog/2017/09/18/the-future-of-hhvm.html) so existing PHP frameworks are no longer appropriate for use under Hack.

[Titon](https://github.com/titon/framework) seems to be the most recently modified Hack framework, though it was last touched in 2015. None of its forked seemed to have been touched too much more recently either.

It looks there are currently no actively maintained Hack frameworks, and whether any will appear unfortunately remains to be seen given the apparent momentum of PHP 7.